What data structure to use for a first-half intensive priority queue?
I have an algorithm which generates a sequence of numbers. Simplified, it looks something like this (pseudocode):
T<int, int[]> dataStructure = new T();

// I'm iterating through an infinite, ascending, sequence of integers.
// Here I'm using `int` but I could just as well use `long` or `BigInt`.
// The point is that I'm iterating through whole numbers.
for (int current = 11; true; i += 2) {
  if (current in dataStructure) {
    // If the current integer is a key in my data structure,
    // I need to remove the entry. I also need to move each of the
    // integers in the value list to index `current + value * 2`.
    int[] values = dataStructure.delete(current);
    for (int value in values) {
      dataStructure[current + value * 2].add(value);
    }
  } else {
    // If the current integer is NOT a key in my data structure,
    // it should be added to the list at index `current * 2`.
    // The current integer should also be yielded as one of the
    // generated by the algorithm.
    dataStructure[current * 3].add(current);
    yield(current);
  }
}

My question is, what data structure should I use for T?
Please note that I'm more concerned with the data structure than the language it is implementated in.

Observations:

I'm looking quite a lot at the lowest value in T.
T looks very much similar to a priority queue.

However, entries do not change priority once queued.
Neither is a decreaseKey function needed.


In the real case, the max number of values per entry in T can be approximated as ceil(log10(key)) + 1.
The number of unique keys in T regularly exceed 100 000+.
Insertions are more likely in, though not limited to, the lower half of T.
Removals are always performed on the lowest entry in T.


Current implementation and thoughts:

Currently, I'm using a java TreeMap with ArrayList values.
I have also tried PriorityQueue and FibonnaciHeap but performance was much worse than TreeMap.
I'm considering offloading entries with large keys in T to disk, e.g. via SQLite, as these are unlikely to be accessed for quite some time.
I'm concerned that using a balanced tree structure for T will lead to a lot of unnecessary node rotations.
I'm concerned that allocating millions of ArrayLists may be inefficient.


Yes, this is a prime number generator in its full form ;)

I mean, it's up to you how much extra work you are willing to put in. If I had all the time in the world, I would use a combination of a HashMap and a self-balancing BST. A hash table gives you fast lookups and the BST handles your ordering and fast key retrieval.

Or consider this SkipList I've never seen an implementation but read about it in my algorithms book.

Interesting. Thank you! I'll need to read up a bit on skip lists. My main concern is performance as in CPU clock cycles. A faster solution is preferred over a smaller memory footprint in this case.

A skip list does seem to make a lot of sense. A sorted linked list seems somewhat ideal, apart from the linear insertion time - which skip list is looking to solve. I'm also thinking that if the array stored in T is sorted, it should be possible to perform multiple inserts without starting the search over from the beginning when using a linked list.

Skip list looks like a good way to do this. You don't mention the implementation language. Skip list is difficult to implement efficiently in C# due to runtime restrictions. Java might have the same limitations. I wrote about this in my blog years ago: https://blog.mischel.com/2010/10/10/c-versus-the-data-structure/
